# Merge sort on a linked list

Tags: java, merge, linked-list, mergesort

So I've been trying to sort a linked list using merge sort, I found this code and tried to work on it, but it doesn't seen to really work?

What could be the problem with it? I'm not quite sure about the getMiddle method although I know it should get the middle value of the list in order to work on 2 lists from the list itself

Here's the code;

```
public Node mergeSort(Node head) {

    if (head == null || head.link == null) {
        return head;       
    }

    Node middle = getMiddle(head);

    Node sHalf = middle.link;
    middle.link = null;       

    return merge(mergeSort(head), mergeSort(sHalf));
}

public Node merge(Node a, Node b) {
    Node dummyHead;
    Node current;

    dummyHead = new Node();
    current = dummyHead;

    while (a != null && b != null) {
        if ((int) a.getData() <= (int) b.getData()) {
            current.link = a;
            a.link = a;
        }
        else {
            current.link = b;
            b.link = a;
        }
        current = current.link;
    }
    current.link = (a == null) ? b : a;
    return dummyHead;
}

public Node getMiddle(Node head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return head;
    }
    Node slow, fast;
    slow = fast = head;
    while (fast.link != null && fast.link.link != null) {
        slow = slow.link;
        fast = fast.link.link;
    }
    return slow;
}
```

In the main method:

```
  Object data;
    MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();         //empty list.


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {           //filling the list
        data = console.nextInt();
        list.insertAtFront(data);
    }


    System.out.print("Print(1): ");
    list.printList();

   list.mergeSort(list.getHead());
    System.out.print("List after sorting: ");
    list.printList();
```

Comment: `What could be the problem with it?` you haven't spend enough time working out what the error is.  What doesn't work, give us a simple example and explain what the error is.

Comment: I figure out with the mergeSort method, it should take  a List as a parameter & not a node so therefore it's gonna return a List. As for the error, it seems that upon method call, there is no output.

Comment: So give us a simple example we can run where this doesn't work and what you expected to happen. i.e. write a unit test which fails.

Comment: Alright, so for a start my list has the following items : 5-2-9-1, I'm supposed to get 1-2-5-9, but when I'm calling the method there is no output, like I don't get a result

Comment: I repeat: can you give me an example I can run?

Comment: What does the MyLinkedList class look like?

Comment: And why are you adding `ints` that are `Objects` instead of `Integers`

Comment: MyLinkedList is where I start building a list, it has methods to add and delete a node in addition to print the list & print it in the reverse order

Comment: Do you have a `setData(Object)` method in your Node class like you have a `getData()`?

Comment: @asaini007 I set the data from the constructor..I have a constructor that assigns data to the node's info part

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the `getMiddle` method doesn't correctly return the middle `Node`.

Consider a linked list with 5 Nodes (a, b, c, d, e)

`head`, `slow`, and `fast` all begin at index 0 (a).

After the first iteration of the `while` loop, `slow` is at 1 (b) and `fast` is at 2 (c); after the second iteration, `slow` is at 2 (c) and fast at 4 (e). These are both not null, so another iteration happens, putting slow at at 3 (d) and fast at `null`. Since `fast` is null, the `while` loop is exited and `slow` is returned; however `slow` has node 3 (d) rather than the middle node, 2 (c).

An alternate way to get the middle node would be to simply use the number of nodes:

```
public Node getMiddle(Node head) {
    Node counter = head;
    int numNodes = 0;
    while(counter != null) {
        counter = counter.link;
        numNodes++;
    }
    if(numNodes == 0)
        return null;
    Node middle = head;
    for(int i=0; i<numNodes/2; i++)
        middle = middle.link;
    return middle;
}
```

I your `mergeSort` method is fine, but technically it only needs to return `head` if `head.link` is `null`, not if `head` itself is `null` (since that would never happen anyhow):

```
public Node mergeSort(Node head) {
    if (head.link == null) {
        return head;       
    }
    // same
}
```

Most importantly, your `merge` method. You can write a `public void setData(Object)` method in your `Node` class to make this easier. The following code should work, although I can't claim it's the best/most efficient way to do the job

```
public Node merge(Node a, Node b) {
    Node combined = new Node();
    Node current = combined;
    while(a != null || b != null) {
        if(a == null)
            addNode(current, b);
        if(b == null)
            addNode(current, a);
        if((int)a.getData()<(int)b.getData())
            addNode(current, a);
        else
            addNode(current, b);
    }
    return combined;
}
```

Uses the following helper method:

```
public void addNode(Node n1, Node n2) {
    n1.setData((int)n2.getData());
    n1.link = new Node();
    n1 = n1.link;
    n2 = n2.link
}
```

Comment: this generates a stackoverflow exception though

Comment: the `getMiddle` method?

Comment: plus this is missing a return statement.

Comment: Yeah updated... this uses a setData() method which would be easy to write

Comment: it should return `combined`... `combined` is the head of the node to return, `current` would be the last node in the linked list

Comment: Yes that's right, but calling the mehod generates a stackoverflow